# Ultra modded survival isnt responding

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I added ultra modded survival to my modpacks in my tekkit launcher, but when I press play, it will load up to the captainsparklez logo, then start to not respond. I tried a different modpack and it worked, but ultra modded survival just won't respond.

Comment: Try to enable console logging to see if it actually still does anything. Also, I'd try to increase available RAM for tekkit to at least 2GB, if not 4-8. Once I used a pack with 200+ mods it took 5-10 minutes to load the pack, so maybe you just didn't wait long enough. That, or it stuck.

Comment: Try changing the load order of the mods. Mods that are larger and have more effect on the game should be at the top of the load order vs mods that affect a small portion/aesthetics. This also may be caused by conflicting item ID's which can be remedied by using idFix (super simple mod to use with great instructions). As private said, allocating more resources can also be a possible remedy. Check to make sure you have the most up-to-date version of java as well. It's amazing the amount of havoc an old version can wreak on the game.

Comment: @private_meta i am currently giving it 1GB. How do i enable console logging?

Comment: @slow_excellence what is the current up to date java version

Comment: It will always be on the java website: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnjp. The current version is 8u5 and you should be using the JRE download (unless you're a java developer)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we do not allow modded minecraft support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost every Big modpack tends to have this issue. for instance if you run the Yogscast Complete pack you will find that it can take up to 10 mins to load completely because it has to initialise all the different mods.

The second thing is you aren't really giving it enough ram most modpacks recommend at least 2 gb - I Have 14gb assigned for My Big modpacks.

I recommend assigning it as much Ram as you can and just leave it to boot up, leave it for 15 mins max if it isn't working after that then there is something else wrong.

The game window will say not responding but that will go away - Promise ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you did not read the whole article 
you need to press the little gear in the corner and top up the memory to 2GB
then it will work